# const keyword in return type of function declaration

Tags: c++, function, constants, return-value, return-type

I have written following 3 functions in C++. Kindly explain me how all return types are different? And how the return values will be stored in Memory? I know const keyword applies to whatever is on immediate left but i need more explanation.

```
const int* sample1();
int* const sample2();
int const* sample3();
```

Comment: 1 and 3 are the same semantically. When it comes to "how is it stored in memory", all three are the same, constness is considered at compile time only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const int* sample1();
int const* sample3();
```

These functions are identical. They return pointer to constant memory (this memory cannot be changed via this pointer). But we can change pointer itself. Increment it for example.

```
int* const sample2();
```

This function returns constant pointer to non-constant memory. We cannot change pointer itself, but we can change the memory it is point.

Comment: You can't change the pointer returned by `sample1` or `sample3` either, in both cases it is an _rvalue_ of non-class type. E.g. `sample1()++;` or `sample3() += 1;` won't compile.

Comment: @CharlesBailey you can change it of course after you assign it to appropriate variable. It is implied.

Comment: @ssgreg: but then it's a different object; you've copied it and you can apply constness independently. You can just as easily do this with `sample2()` so it's not a difference between any of the three functions. E.g. `int * p = sample2(); p++;`

Answer (score 0):

*const* does not have to *apply to whatever is on immediate right*. For example

```
class Foo
{ 
  void Bar() const;
  int var;
}
```

This will will ban the function *Bar* in *Foo* to alter any member variables in the object.
Besides this *us2012*'s comment sums it all up.

I might be totally of but this seems like a school assignment or something?